# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! error GO

Tags: go, concurrency

I'm new to concurrency in Go so I tried an example with channels and goroutines. I want to have the producer-consumer pattern. The producer function forever gives random strings and the consumer modifies them by making them uppercase. I want to run it for a limited time(2 sec).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func producer(x []string, c chan string) {
    i := 1
    for i > 0 {
        randomIndex := rand.Intn(len(x))
        pick := x[randomIndex]
        c <- pick
    }
}

func consumer(x string, c chan string) {
    x1 := strings.ToUpper(x)
    c <- x1
}

func main() {

    s := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four"}
    c1 := make(chan string)
    d1 := make(chan string)
    go producer(s, c1)
    go consumer(<-c1, d1)

    stop := time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println("STOP AFTER 2 SEC!")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println(<-d1)
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting only one array element and some errors. What changes need to be made so this example would work?

OUTPUT:

TWO

fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.producer({0xc00004e040, 0x4, 0x0?}, 0x0?)
created by main. main
exit status 2

Comment: your consumer runs only once. Put it in a for-loop

Comment: Thx, this seems to be the pb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your consumer should run in a loop, this has been mentioned already.

Change the first parameter of the consumer so that it is a `chan string` instead of a string. That way the producer can continuously write to this channel for the consumer to publish on another channel until the time limit expires.

```
func consumer(consumeChan chan string, outCh chan string) {
    for {
        select {
        case s := <- consumeChan:
            s = strings.ToUpper(s)
            outCh <- s
        }
    }
}
```

Right now in the main func before `go consumer()` is called you are waiting for the first response to the `c1` channel from the producer. Instead of doing that pass in the `c1` channel as the first parameter.

```
func main() {
    s := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four"}
    c1 := make(chan string)
    d1 := make(chan string)
    go producer(s, c1)
    go consumer(c1, d1)

    stop := time.After(2000 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println("STOP AFTER 2 SEC!")
            return
        case response := <- d1:
            fmt.Println(response)
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

This should show you continuous writes of random numbers by the producer on the `c1` channel, and continuous writes on the d1 channel by the consumer with the text in all uppercase until the 2 seconds is up.